# Flutter - GridView Custom Size Issue

Tags: flutter, gridview, resize, flutter-layout, flutter-container

I have been experimenting with flutter and GridView. Currently I have a number of containers appearing in a grid layout, however I want to add one more container below them and custom size it. I want all the existing containers to consume 60% of the screen, whereas the new container to completely cover the remaining 40%. I have experimented with Expanded Class with no luck. Any feedback / recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

````
     Widget build(BuildContext context){
       final title = ' MyFirstApp';
       
       return MaterialApp(
         title: title,
         home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.green,
          title: Text(title),
        ),
        body: GridView.count(
          
          crossAxisCount: 3,
          crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
          mainAxisSpacing: 10.0,
          childAspectRatio: 0.80, 
           children: <Widget> [ 
             new InkWell(
              onTap: (){
                navigateToSubPage(context, Page1());
                print("Container clicked");
              },
            child: Container(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                   Image.asset('assets/main/page1.jpg'),
                  Text("Page1", style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 18),),
                ]),
          )


          ),
            new InkWell(
              onTap: (){
                navigateToSubPage(context, page2());
                print("Container clicked 1");
              },
            child: Container(
             child: Column(
              children: [
                Image.asset('assets/main/page2.jpg'),
                Text("Page2", style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 18),),
              ]),
            ),
          ),
          new InkWell(
              onTap: (){
                navigateToSubPage(context, page3());
                print("Container clicked 2");
              },
            child: Container(
               child: Column(
                children: [
                  Image.asset('assets/main/page3.jpg'),
                  Text("Record", style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 18),),
              ]),
              
            ),
           ),
          new InkWell(
              onTap: (){
                navigateToSubPage(context, page4());
                print("Container clicked 3");
            },
            child: Container(
               child: Column(
                children: [
                  Image.asset('assets/main/page4.jpg'),
                  Text("Page4", style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 18),)
                ]),
            ),
           ),
           new InkWell(
              onTap: (){
                print("Container clicked 4");
            },
            child: Container(
               child: Column(
                children: [
                 Image.asset('assets/main/page5.jpg'),
                 Text("Page5", style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 18),),
                ]),
            ),
           ),
           new InkWell(
              onTap: (){
                print("Container clicked 5");
            },
          ),

          ],  
                               
        ),        
        ),
       );
  }```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, [GridView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GridView-class.html) is scrollable since there are times that a grid could contain a large (or infinite) number of children that wouldn't fit in the entire screen. If this is not what you wanted to achieve, then I suggest just using [rows and columns](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout#lay-out-multiple-widgets-vertically-and-horizontally).

Also, if you will check the properties of `GridView.count()` by using the "Go To Definition" operation in the IDE of your choice,it will lead you to the ***scroll_view.dart*** file. `mainAxisSpacing`, `crossAxisSpacing` and `childAspectRatio` are the properties whose values could be customized. So I think you'll just need to play with those properties to get your desired `height` and `width` of those containers.

Based on my understanding, what you'd like to achieve is something like this:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final title = ' MyFirstApp';

return MaterialApp(
  title: title,
  home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.green,
      title: Text(title),
    ),
    body: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          flex: 60,
          child: GridView.count(
            crossAxisCount: 3,
            crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
            mainAxisSpacing: 10.0,
            childAspectRatio: 0.80,
            children: <Widget>[
              new InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    // navigateToSubPage(context, Page1());
                    print("Container clicked");
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.green[100],
                    child: Column(children: [
                      // Image.asset('assets/main/page1.jpg'),
                      Text(
                        "Page1",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 18),
                      ),
                    ]),
                  )),
              new InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  // navigateToSubPage(context, page2());
                  print("Container clicked 1");
                },
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.green[200],
                  child: Column(children: [
                    // Image.asset('assets/main/page2.jpg'),
                    Text(
                      "Page2",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 18),
                    ),
                  ]),
                ),
              ),
              new InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  // navigateToSubPage(context, page3());
                  print("Container clicked 2");
                },
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.green[300],
                  child: Column(children: [
                    // Image.asset('assets/main/page3.jpg'),
                    Text(
                      "Record",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 18),
                    ),
                  ]),
                ),
              ),
              new InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  // navigateToSubPage(context, page4());
                  print("Container clicked 3");
                },
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.green[400],
                  child: Column(children: [
                    // Image.asset('assets/main/page4.jpg'),
                    Text(
                      "Page4",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 18),
                    )
                  ]),
                ),
              ),
              new InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  print("Container clicked 4");
                },
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.green[500],
                  child: Column(children: [
                    // Image.asset('assets/main/page5.jpg'),
                    Text(
                      "Page5",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 18),
                    ),
                  ]),
                ),
              ),
              new InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  print("Container clicked 5");
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          flex: 40,
          child: GridView.count(
            crossAxisCount: 1,
            children: <Widget>[
              new InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    // navigateToSubPage(context, Page1());
                    print("Container clicked");
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.green[600],
                    child: Column(children: [
                      // Image.asset('assets/main/page1.jpg'),
                      Text(
                        "Remaining 40%",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 18),
                      ),
                    ]),
                  )),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);}
```

[image]

Reusing your code (commented out some parts not needed and enhanced for visual purposes), I wrapped the 2 `GridView.count()` into 2 separate [`Expanded()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) widget, so that I could set the `flex factor` to 60 and 40 respectively. On the 2nd `GridView.count()` I set the `crossAxisCount` to 1 to fill the remaining 40% of the screen.

Comment: Thanks. Greatly appreciated :)